# how to have a jquery fade animation with html/css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to come up with a duplicate of [this](http://jirungu2012.wix.com/firebrandoption2)

I want to duplicate the flame icons. These appear in each section on the far right or left away from the central container where we have text.

```
<section id="ourfires" class="portfolio page-section add-top add-bottom">
    <!-- inner-section : starts -->
    <section class="inner-section">
        <!-- container : starts -->
        <section class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <article class="col-md-12">
                    <h1 style="text-align:left;"><span class="animated" data-fx="bounceInRight">Our fire</span></h1>
                    <article id="article"><hr class="hr"></hr></article>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div id="mid">
                        <p class="promod-text dark-text">Our fire is all about <b>Big Brand Ideas</b> that not only have an <b>edge in the market</b> and make a difference in the <b>bottom line</b>,but ieas are: </p>
                        <div>
                            <ul id="navlist" class="promod-text dark-text" >
                                <li>Locally relevant</li>
                                <li>Creatively imagined and executed</li>
                                <li>Internationally recognized</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </article>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- container : ends -->
    </section>
    <!-- inner-section : ends -->
    </div>
</section>
```

---

```
#ourfires{
   background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Yeah then - go ahead!

Comment: yea i tried but my code  doesnt show the flame.

Comment: @connexo yes i have managed to put the flame check [this](http://www.inspirodesigns.co.ke/job/firebrand/) the only issue is now how do i make the flame to be on the background and outside the main container so that it doesnt appear to be pushing the text downwards

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the icon fade in when the page arrive to the position of the fire icon you have to use js because you have to know when the icon is on the screen, so the js is only to change the class when the icon is on the screen, all the animation is with css, the idea is change the `opacity` from 0 to 1 to the element that you want fade in and set a `transition` to animate the process, for that you can use

```js
var elementToAnimate = document.querySelector(".fire-icon");
var heightViewPort = window.innerHeight;


function foundPosition(){
    /* SCROLL DISTANCE */
    var desplaced = self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    /* DESPLACED + HALF OF VIEWPORT, FOR TO ANIMATE THE ICON WHEN IT ARRIVE TO THE HALF OF THE SCREEN */
    var positionAnimate = desplaced + (heightViewPort / 2);

    if(elementToAnimate.offsetTop < positionAnimate){
        elementToAnimate.classList.add("animate-css");
    }
}

onscroll = foundPosition;
```

```css
html, body, .big-div{
    height: 100%;
}

.fire-icon{
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}

.fire-icon.animate-css{
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
SCROLL TO SEE THE ANIMATION
<div class="big-div"></div>
    <div class="fire-icon">
        <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/d57153_09c71d3fe10848c3a04b18f8d8a6c2b3.png_srz_p_487_587_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_png_srz" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="big-div"></div>
```

You can customize the animation as you wish, the above is only an example to illustrate, or also you can use animate.css.

You can see http://ksesocss.blogspot.com/2015/06/javascript-con-furoya-lazy-load-estoy.html it will help you a lot.

[Here a jsfiddle to play with.](http://jsfiddle.net/8gzyjpeg/)

Comment: yes i have managed to put the flame check [this](http://www.inspirodesigns.co.ke/job/firebrand/) the only issue is now how do i make the flame to be on the background and outside the main container

Comment: @BillehSarkozy probably you have to set a height to div.fire-icon because if you set the img as a background the div will not have a content so its height will be 0, this is a working jsfiddel with the img as backgroud http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/jk18j7cx/2/. On the other hand what do you mean with "outside the main container", which one is the "main container"

Comment: the flame icon is now the background but how do i put text in the middle.So that the flame is on the far left and text in the middle all aligned the same.Main container is where i will put the text then on the far left i put the flame icon

Comment: also how do i replicate the flames to the other sections.When I add the same class it affects the height of the documents

Comment: @BillehSarkozy I really want to help you, but be more specific in what you want to achieve and define it in once, first you want "have a jquery fade animation with html/css" then the img as BG now the the text in the middle, please let me know which one is exactly the problem that you are having.

Comment: when you check [this](http://jirungu2012.wix.com/firebrandoption2) you notice that sections have flame icons  that pop out to the left and right as you move down that is what I want to achieve.From what we have done so far we have managed to put the fade animation and make it as a background now how do i make it have text in the middle and then copy it down to all sections.Hope am clear now?

Comment: @BillehSarkozy check out this http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/jk18j7cx/4/ note that I change a few things in the code